# su - -c 'll' other_user results in error, how can I run this other user's alias?

Tags: bash, su

In current bash session, I just want to change to another user for some bash command. The command is aliased to some script defined in another user's `.bashrc` or `.profile`.

Am I able to make it possible while not changing to this other user directly? like:

```
$ su - -c 'll' other_user_name
-> command not found: ll
```

While `ll` was defined in other user's `~/.bashrc`?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
su --login -c 'bash -ic "ll"' test
```

which will put you in user `test`'s home directory, or:

```
su  -c 'bash -ic "ll"' test
```

which leaves you in your current directory.